# Permanently disable screensaver Fedora 19

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, gnome, screensaver

I am creating a bash script that will 'setup' a client machine running Fedora 19 (GNOME). I need to be able to permanently disable the screensaver with no user input. 
I found some (granted, old) documentation that suggested you could simply set the idle-activation-enabled to false:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

This shows the change has been made (returns false):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled
```

This however does not stop the screen from dimming and locking the screen. Does anyone have any ideas? Is this a problem with terminology? Is the screen dimming function not referred to as a screen saver?

Answer (score 6):

In Fedora 19, org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.idle-activation-enabled is deprecated and ignored. Set org.gnome.desktop.session.idle-delay to 0 if you do not want the screensaver to be activated.

Answer (score 6):

I had to implement this requirement for a Fedora 19 virtual machine.  I ran the following using the terminal as root to disable the screensaver:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

You can verify it was set correctly by running:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
```

Comment: Default is 300, just in case you want to reverse that.